# scm checkout only specific branches with matched regex pattern

Tags: git, jenkins

Have a repo with branches like /release/1.2.3, /release/2.3.4, /release/test, /release/test1

In Declarative pipeline, at checkout GitSCM, trying to checkout only specific branches with regex pattern.

```
branches: [[name: "origin/release/\d{*}.\d{*}.\d{*}"]]
```

ex: origin/release/2.3.4 or other branches with matched pattern.

But git checkout is occurring even if pattern not matched.

Comment: Do you want every branch starting from `/release` ? And have you used `when {}` in the pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

It worked when modified the branch specifier as

```
branches: [[name: ":origin/release/\\d*\\.\\d*\\.\\d*"]]
```

and triggered only branches with matched pattern.

Comment: @VonC, When I add the the leading colon ( : ) , builds triggered with pattern. What I noticed is it is not triggered all the branches. I created the new jenkins job and just added the git checkout step. When polling enabled jenkins job was triggered with oldest branch first and then to latest, but it missed few branches in between. I worried what could be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Following the [Built-in Condition examples](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#built-in-conditions), you might try:

```
when { branch pattern: "release/\\d*.\\d*.\\d*", comparator: "REGEXP"}
```

This uses, as commented, the  `when` directive, which allows the Pipeline to determine whether the stage should be executed depending on the given condition.

Comment: That's what I asked in the comments. Whether he is using `when {}` or not? Maybe the problem could be in regex pattern or something?

Comment: Yes, that is why I added in the answer "as commented". Let us wait for the OP's comment/feedback.